# C++ alignas(1) does not affect the size of a struct

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct alignas(1) H1 {
    uint8_t f8;
    uint64_t f64;
};

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct H3 {
    uint8_t f8;
    uint64_t f64;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main() {
    std::cout << "H1 " << sizeof(H1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "H3 " << sizeof(H3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
$ ./a.out
H1 16
H3 9
```

The `alignas(1)` did not affect the size of `H1` while `#pragma` did.
On the contrary, `alignas(64)` actually increases the size of a struct.

Comment: fsquirrel, Why do you expect the alignment should affect the size?

Comment: You appear to have failed to ask a question

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. The first case uses `alignas` to affect the alignment of the structure as a whole. The second case uses `#pragma pack` to affect the alignment within the structure. Why would these have the same effect?

Answer (score 2):

https://godbolt.org/z/bodnG3

```
<source>:3:8: error: requested alignment is less than minimum alignment of 8 for type 'H1'
struct alignas(1) H1 {
       ^
1 error generated.
```

Your program is ill-formed. You are not allowed to weaken alignment requirements using `alignas`.